# Kendo Jquery Grid - Filtering on comma separated values column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a Kendo Jquery Grid and we are trying to provide filter on Column where we are showing values in comma separated form. Code is shown below, I have tried to catch the filter object in dataBound event and try to filter out records over datasource, but couldn't help. Please suggest how can we achieve this.

Field on which we need to achieve this is *ProviderSpecialty*

```
<script>
    var grid;
    var dataSource;
    var gridView = 'updatesRequired';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectGridView').change(function () {
            gridView = $('#selectGridView').val();
            $('#grid').kendoGrid('destroy').empty();
            renderGrid();
        });
        renderGrid();
    });

    function renderGrid() {

        var fieldsSchema =
        {
            'ProviderDelegateId': { type: 'number' },
            'EndDate': {type: 'date' }
        };
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: providerProfileApiBaseUrl)
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                if (e.xhr.responseText != '') {
                    var jsonError = JSON.parse(e.xhr.responseText);

                    if (myApp.Web.utility.displacolumns !== undefined) {
                        myApp.Web.utility.displacolumns.push({
                            field: 'EndDate', template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(EndDate), "MM/dd/yyyy")#', title: 'Campaign End Dt', width: '125px', filterable: {
                                ui: function (element) {
                                    element.kendoDatePicker({
                                        format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    myApp.Web.utility.displayErrorDialog(jsonError.error);
                }
            },
            pageSize: myApp.Web.config.grid.pageable.pageSize,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'UniqueId',
                    fields: fieldsSchema
                }
            },
            sort: { field: "ProviderLastName", dir: "asc" }
        });

        var columns = [];
        columns.push({ field: 'ProviderDelegateId', hidden: true });
        if (gridView === 'updatesRequired') {
            columns.push({ field: 'ProviderLastName', title: 'Last Name', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderLanding/ProviderUpdate/Index/#=CampaignTrackingId#">#=ProviderLastName#</a>' });
            columns.push({ field: 'ProviderFirstName', title: 'First Name', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderLanding/ProviderUpdate/Index/#=CampaignTrackingId#">#=ProviderFirstName#</a>' });
            columns.push({ field: 'ProviderNPI', title: 'NPI', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderLanding/ProviderUpdate/Index/#=CampaignTrackingId#">#=ProviderNPI != null ? ProviderNPI : \'\' #</a>' });
        } else {
            columns.push({ field: 'ProviderLastName', title: 'Last Name', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderUpdate/UpdateProfile?providerId=#=ProviderId#">#=ProviderLastName#</a>' });
            columns.push({ field: 'ProviderFirstName', title: 'First Name', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderUpdate/UpdateProfile?providerId=#=ProviderId#">#=ProviderFirstName#</a>' });
            columns.push({ field: 'ProviderNPI', title: 'NPI', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderUpdate/UpdateProfile?providerId=#=ProviderId#">#=ProviderNPI != null ? ProviderNPI : \'\' #</a>' });
        };
        columns.push({ field: 'ProviderSpecialty', title: 'Specialty', width: '125px', template: '#= getSpecialties(ProviderSpecialties) #' });
        columns.push({ field: 'ProviderEmail', title: 'Email', width: '125px' });
        columns.push({ field: 'LocationName', title: 'Location', width: '125px', template: '#= getLocations(ProviderLocations) #'  });
        if (gridView === 'updatesRequired') {
            columns.push({ field: 'CampaignName', title: 'Campaign', width: '125px', template: '<a href="/ProviderLanding/ProviderUpdate/Index/#=CampaignTrackingId#">#=CampaignName#</a>' });
            columns.push({
                field: 'EndDate', template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(EndDate), "MM/dd/yyyy")#', title: 'Campaign End Dt', width: '125px', filterable : {
                ui: function (element) {
                    element.kendoDatePicker({
                        format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
                    });
                }
            } });
        } else {
            columns.push({ field: 'IsPendingChangeAvailable', title: 'Pending Changes', width: '125px', template: '#if (IsPendingChangeAvailable) {# Yes #} else {# No #}#' });
        };

        grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            columns: columns,
            scrollable: false,
            filterable: myApp.Web.config.grid.filterable,
            sortable: myApp.Web.config.grid.sortable,
            pageable: myAppWeb.config.grid.pageable,
        }).data('kendoGrid');
    };

    function getSpecialties(specialties) {
        // remove duplicates and then join...
        var result = [];
        $.each(specialties, function(i, e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.SpecialtyName, result) == -1) result.push(e.SpecialtyName);
        });
        return result.join(',');
    };

    function getLocations(locations) {
        return locations.map(function (location) {
            return location.LocationName
        }).join(',');
    };

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#overlay-screen').show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#overlay-screen').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter box will not allow you to add in a comma. I am not sure you can do this with a comma unless you override the UI to show your own filter box and on change apply the filter via jquery/javascript like below. If I am understanding you correctly.

```
//After user enters their values. Imagine "Tom,John" would be what the user entered
//After you exploded the comma list yourself
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({
    logic: "or",
    filters: [
       { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: 'Tom' },
       { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: 'John' },
    ]
});
```

Obviously, it would be a little more advanced if you are allowing other columns to be filtered as well.  You would instead be modifying the filter rather than overriding them.  Note my example uses contains.  This could be eq if you wanted that. However, assuming that column you want to filter by is text you could instead use the "mulit: true" on the filterable object. This allows the selections to be managed by the user with kendo's UI element

```
//On the column property
filterable: {
    multi:true
}
```

This will give you check boxes for each possible value in the column.  Note if you mode on the filterable object of your grid is set to row.  This will not work

```
//On the grid
filterable: {
    mode: "row"
}
```

Open the code from the following link within the dojo
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.multi

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**This problem can be solved by altering the default behaviour of the grid in three places.**

**1. Altering the configuration of the given column**

Add a additional property to the column filterable configuration to indicate that special logic should be applied.
column.filterable = { multi: true, isCommaSeparatedList: true}

**2. Altering the datasource of the multi select during filter menu initialization (filterMenuInit event)**
Get the column from the grids columns collection and check if the filterable object contains the userdefined property "isCommaSeparatedList".

```
 filterMenuInit(event: kendo.ui.GridFilterMenuInitEvent) {
        const field = event.field;

        //Get the column where the user wants to set the filter
        filteredColumn = event.sender.columns.filter((column) => { return column.field === field })[0] as kendo.ui.GridColumn;
        if (filteredColumn && typeof filteredColumn.filterable === "object" && filteredColumn.filterable["isCommaSeparatedList"]) {

            //Declare an array to hold the unique select items
            var selectItems = new Array();

            //Declare an dictionary for fast lookup
            var valuesDictionary = new Object();

            //Get the data from the grid
            const gridRecords = event.sender.dataSource.data().toJSON();

            //Loop the records an find the individual values in the comma separated list
            for (let gridRecord of gridRecords) {
                const values = gridRecord[field].toString().split(",") as Array<string>;
                values.forEach((value) => {
                    value = value.trim();
                    //If the value is not found in the dictionary then the value is added to the dictionary and the selectItems Array
                    if (!valuesDictionary[value]) {
                        valuesDictionary[value] = true;
                        selectItems.push({ [field]: value });
                    }
                });
            }

            //Sort the selectItems
            selectItems.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a[field] < b[field]) return -1;
                else if (a[field] > b[field]) return 1;
                return 0;
            });

            //Set the datasource for the multi select column to the items found
            const filterable = filteredColumn.filterable as any as kendo.ui.GridColumnFilterable;
            filterable.dataSource.data(selectItems);
        }
```

**3. Alter the filter when the user has checked or unchecked one or more items (filter event)**
If the filterable property of a column is set to {multi: true} then when changing the filter by checking or uncheckeing a checkbox in the filter menu will lead to a filter with the operator set to "eq". This is not wat we want. Because the underlying datasource contains a comma separated list. So we want the operator to be "contains". The trick I use is to duplicate the filter expression in the grid "filter" event. I loop over all filters applied to the given column and add the same filter but with the operator = "contains"

```
       filter: (event: kendo.ui.GridFilterEvent) => {
            //This function is called each time the filter in the grid is changed.
            if (event.filter) {
                //Try to get the column definition from the columns dictionary for the column where the filter has changed.
                const column = event.sender.columns.filter((column) => { return column.field === event.field })[0] as kendo.ui.GridColumn;

                //Find out if the filterable property of the column is set to an object and if the object has a property "isList"
                if (column && column.filterable && typeof column.filterable === "object" && column.filterable["isCommaSeparatedList"]) {
                    //Duplicate all the filters with an operator = "eq" to a filter with operator = "contains"
                    for (let filter of event.filter.filters) {
                        if (filter.operator === "eq" && !filter["handled"]) {
                             //Add a handled property to check if the filter has already been duplicated to prevent an endless loop
                            filter["handled"] = true;
                            event.filter.filters.push({ value: filter.value, operator: "contains", field: filter.field });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

## Hopefully this works for you